# Set numericDates=true from Smartsheets Java API

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

I am reading the values of cells from a SmartSheet sheet, but would prefer the DateTime information in the modified column to be numeric.  The API reference says I can set numericDates=true to accomplish this, but I can not figure out how or where to include/set this from java.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, numericDates is a query string parameter, so you'd tack it on to the end of the URL, like so:

```
GET https://api.smartshhet.com/2.0/sheets/12345?numericDates=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was trying to do this using the Java API